# How to detect when a global variable is set in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a wait to detect when a global variable has change or set in React Native. With my code I have no choice but to use a global variable however I need to know when it has been changed. I can't pass it as a prop and don't want to use context

```
//process.js

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, globalVariable) {
    console.info(prevProps);
    console.info(globalVariable)

    console.log(globel.task) // I only want to detect when there is a change or when the global variable is set
  }


// globalVariable.js

  global.task = 'something'
  global.transfer = 'some data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `states` like

```
this.state = { var1: '', var2: ''}
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state.var1);
}
```

...

```
any_method() {
  this.setState({var1: 'new_value'});
}
```